# dojo.deferred and for loop

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have an array of values that get passed to a function. The function loops over the array and uses the values in another method.

This works fine for the first value in the array, then all other item' I get an error: "This deferred has already been resolved".

I would like to end up with an array of responses, it currently stops after 1 response?

Any help? 
thanks!

```
function showQueryResults(searchResults){
    function getFacIds(arr){
        var def = new dojo.Deferred();
        for (var i = 0, iLen = arr.features.length; i < iLen; i++) {
            findParams.searchText = searchResults.features[i].attributes.ID;
            findTask.execute(findParams, function(response){
                def.callback(response);
            });
        };
        return def;
    };              
    getFacIds(searchResults).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`Deferred`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/Deferred.html) can only be resolved once. You need to track the responses.

In Dojo 1.7 syntax, assuming no errors:

```
require(["dojo/Deferred", "dojo/_base/array", "example/async"],
                                              function(Deferred, array, async) {
  var foo = function (arr) {
    var def, results, index;
    def = new Deferred();
    results = [];
    array.forEach(arr, function(item, index) {
      async(arr[index], function (r) {
        results.push(r);
        if(results.length === arr.length) {
          def.callback(results);
        }
      });
    }
    return def;
  };

  foo([1, 2, 3]).then(function (results) {
    //do something with the results
  });
}
```

Comment: for some reason the for loop would stop after the first item in array, so I used dojo.forEach(arr, function(entry,i){......however,    i===arr.length doesn't work because i is not in order. 0, 2, 3 -> def.callback is fired but there's 1 more entry?

Comment: @dan - Ah, yes, there were about 3 bugs in that code. The edited code is untested too, but hopefully it's better. The new code checks by array length but doesn't return results in order. If you care about result order, use `results[index] = r;` instead of `push`.

Comment: For anyone struggling.  def.callback(results) line should actually be def.resolve(results) for it to work.